# Getting the last occurrence of a day/month in PHP

Tags: php, strtotime, unix-timestamp

I'm wondering if there's an easy way (like using strtotime) whereby I can get the unix time for the last occurrence of a day/month combination. For example, if I was to ask for "1st of September" today (9th May 2012) I would get 1314835200 (1st Sep 2011), but if the code was to run again this October, I would get 1346457600 (1st Sep 2012), and the same if I ran it 1 year from now.

Being able to do it forwards as well as backwards would be a massive bonus.

Comment: I'd recommend having a search, http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bphp%5D+last+day+of+the+month There are quite a few examples. **Top tip** In the search if you put your chosen tags in [php] then you can restrict search to just that tag :)

Comment: @DavidYell You might want to re-read the question

Comment: possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=get+next+occurence+of+a+date+php&submit=search

Comment: Duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/q/7699529/212940

Comment: Thanks for your comments, I did a search (as you know, Stackoverflow even searches for you before you post), but didn't find an answer to my question, hence my posting. I don't believe that any of the links posted are, in fact, the same question.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
$month = 9;
$day = 1;

$timestamp = mktime(0, 0, 0, $month, $day);
if ($timestamp > time()) {
    $timestamp = mktime(0, 0, 0, $month, $day, date('Y') - 1);
}
```

Comment: This certainly does the job. It can also look forwards (i.e. return the next 1st of September) by changing the > to < and - to +.
Unless someone amazes me with a 1-liner (I suspect there isn't one, save for ternary operators) I'll go with this answer.

Comment: why do you answer duplicates?

Comment: @Gordon Because it was easier than finding an appropriate dupe. Don't tell me somebody downvoted me for that?

Comment: @deceze of course they did. Repwhoring is discouraged, unfair and contributing to making finding suitable dupes harder. See http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/105231/168606.

Comment: @Gordon Oh great, as if I need to rep whore. Terribly sorry if I have offended anyone by helping the OP out... -_-# BTW, I did not see you finding a perfect duplicate either...

Comment: @deceze true, I nowadays close most date related questions as too localized because I cannot be bothered anymore to wade through the thousands of answers that say use `mktime`, `date`, `strtotime` or `datetime`, which should give any OP enough pointers to solve questions like this on their own.